# Reducing File Size via Opening a Query Connection VBA

Tags: excel, vba, connection, pivot-table

Currently, I have a workbook filled with several Pivot Tables loaded through huge databases put into the Data Model as connections only. While this method is less memory-intensive as loading as a whole table, I can't seem to get the file size below 100MB--let alone my goal of 30MB.

So, I created a Macro to load the query connections into the Data Model and set up the exact same Pivot Tables after manually deleting the connections in a copy. As I am testing the VBA code, the query shows up in the panel, but I receive the error "Expression.Error: Invalid identifier" despite all the column names being correct with their respective types. Additionally, in VBA, I get this, "Run-time error '1004' We couldn't get data from the Data Model. Here's the error message we got: [Expression.Error] The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly". Note: This is just the beginning of the code. No Pivot Tables are being built yet which is further in the script.

I made a test document and recorded the exact same steps in the Macro. This code seems to work fine and I have both the query and the Data Model connection. Does this error have to do with the number of columns in the query because my data has over 200? I plan to have this code run upon opening the file, so the file size balloons then. Below is the working test code.

```
Sub Testing()
'
' Testing Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Test Data", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Test Data.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=3, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Rank"", Int64.Type}, {" & _
    """Cat"", type text}, {""Sales"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
Workbooks("Test").Connections.Add2 "Query - Test Data", _
    "Connection to the 'Test Data' query in the workbook.", _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Test Data;Extended Properties=" _
    , """Test Data""", 6, True,     False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have >200 columns, but your code has:

`...[Delimiter="","", Columns=3, Encoding=65001, ...`

If you don't need to specify the number of columns to be imported then you can remove that part:

`...[Delimiter="","", Encoding=65001, ...`